# How to upload image from another site

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the simplest way to upload an image from another site to my image folder.   I don't need to rename or re size, or find it on the page, I would just like to take a full path like http://www.mlbtraderumors.com/images/logo.png and have logo.png uploaded to my images directory.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have tried and include an explanation of how your current code fails to meet your needs.

Comment: Do you have an upload form? If so, just paste the URL in the upload field and it will upload the file.

Comment: Best of luck, we would like to see it work :)

Comment: @relentless: It would just post the URL, not the file.

Comment: It would upload the file to a tmp folder, and you could access it, I think?

Comment: @RocketHazmat If you supply an upload dialog box with a URL, it will upload the file.

Comment: I think this is related: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: @relentless: Really?  You've tested that?

Comment: @TobSpr: Huh?  I think you be right...

Comment: If you have a simple <form> with an input[type="file"] it will get uploaded to a temp directory, and is available via the global variable $_FILE[0]

Comment: @TobSpr: Didn't know that... neat little trick :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yep, I do it all the time. Try it out.

Comment: @relentless: I did!  That's an awesome trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want to achieve?

```
$source = file_get_contents("http://www.mlbtraderumors.com/images/logo.png");
file_put_contents("images/logo.png", $source);
```

It will copy the image to your images folder ..

Comment: If you downvote, please consider to tell my why!

Comment: I'm curious myself...

Comment: Hi, I tried this and nothing is happening

Comment: You should have a logo.png in the folder images/ .. if you have no folder images, you won't see anything, of course .. be sure the folder images/ exists relative to the php script you are running.

Comment: Nevermind, I screwed up, it does work!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

First, use imagecreatefromjpeg($url):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functio...tefromjpeg.php

Then, use imagecreatetruecolor():
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functio...etruecolor.php

Then, use imagecopyresampled():
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functio...yresampled.php

And lastly, use imagejpeg():
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: That's a lot for one image. :)